# How could've Japan's Crown Princess foolproof guaranteed her letter of passage to Robert Childan?

Tags: written-material

Pre-suppose the background and context in the TV series *Man in High Castle*. If you remember the details I forgot, just edit this please.

I can't remember why and what episode, but the Crown Princess Michiko hands a letter of safe passage to Robert Childan (Brennan Brown). If I remember, it contains her seal.

I can't remember at what second. In [Season 4 Episode 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_in_the_High_Castle_(TV_series)#Season_4_(2019)), Childan and his new wife Yukiko are trying to board a ship to Japan. But a very disrespectful, unmannered rude Japanese male soldier allows just Yukiko. Childan shows him the Crown Princess's letter, but the soldier alleges it's fake and refuses it. Then Childan and Yukiko try to bribe the soldier, but it fails. Ultimately, only Yukiko sails away on the ship, and Childan watches her leave.

What could the Crown Princess have done to that letter to foolproof it, so that nobody can distrust it? I'm not asking about other solutions, like giving Robert her phone number in case of emergencies.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on scifi.SE or the movies & TV site.

Comment: Rhandai, one of the rules of our site is that third-party worlds are not allowed. At a guess, you didn't mean to post that question here, but rather at [scifi.se] or on [tv.se].

Comment: Posted here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236931/how-couldve-japans-crown-princess-foolproof-guaranteed-her-letter-of-passage-t